# Сортировка по заданному временному промежутку pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется csv таблица с колонками date,user,event_type,parameter, в колонке date записаны даты в формате 2020-04-18 00:00:16, мне нужно написать проверку, сделал ли пользователь в течении 20 минут какие либо действия(то есть в колонках event_type,parameter есть записи от одинакового user за 20 минут). Ниже фрагмент моего кода, который выделяет нужный период времени

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('as.csv', parse_dates=['date'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('_', ' '))
df = df.set_index(['date'])
s = df.loc['2020-04-18 00:00:16':'2020-04-30 23:59:08']
print(s['user'])
```

вывод такой:

```
date

    2020-04-18 00:00:16    178330
    2020-04-18 00:00:24    251435
    2020-04-18 00:00:34    214916
    2020-04-18 00:00:40    782618
    2020-04-18 00:00:42    532810
                            ...  
    2020-04-30 23:58:09    726574
    2020-04-30 23:58:44    843140
    2020-04-30 23:58:49    669680
    2020-04-30 23:59:01    816185
    2020-04-30 23:59:08    622989
    Name: user, Length: 97198, dtype: int64
```

Comment: похоже вы забыли сформулировать сам вопрос)

Comment: мне нужно написать проверку, сделал ли пользователь в течении 20 минут какие либо действия(то есть в колонках event_type,parameter есть записи от одинакового user за 20 минут).

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)